# Who was the first Sri Vaishnava Acharya to quote from the Srimad Bhagavatam?

Tags: history, puranas, bhagavata-purana, vaishnavism, sri-vaishnava

Among the eighteen Mahapuranas, perhaps the most popular one among Vaishnavas today is the Bhagavata Purana, AKA the Srimad Bhagavatam.  Yet Ramanujacharya, the most prominent member of the Sri Vaishnava sect (of which I'm a member) doesn't quote from it at all in his writings.

Various explanations of this have been proposed, e.g. that the Bhagavatam was viewed as having Advaita overtones until the time of Madhvacharya, or that the Bhagavatam was a devotional text and thus not suited for Ramunjacharya's philosophical arguments with his opponents.  Still, a lot of Western Indologists use this fact to argue that the Srimad Bhagavatam was a later work composed after the time of Ramanujacharya, and that all the passages in Hindu scripture (e.g. in other Puranas and the Mahabharata) which refer to the Bhagavatam are later interpolations.

But my purpose here isn't to adjudicate this dispute, other then to say that as a Sri Vaishnava I personally accept the Srimad Bhagavatam as an authentic work composed by Vyasa. My question is, who was the first Sri Vaishnava Acharya who actually quoted from the Srimad Bhagavatam in his works?

Note that I'm not looking for allusions to stories that happen to be in the Srimad Bhagavatam.  I'm looking for direct quotes from the text of the Bhagavatam.  And I'm specifically interested in Sri Vaishnava Acharyas, since the Bhagavatam now plays such a prominent role in the Sri Vaishnava sect.

Comment: @@Keshav-Sri Sudarsana suri, (senior contemporary of Vedanta Desika and Pillai Lokaacharya)  the famous author of sruthaprakasika, has written a commentary on srimad bhagavatham called Shuka paksheeya. Another commentary on bhagavatham, a detailed one was written by Sri VeeraRaghavachary (14 century AD?) from Vishistadvaita point of view. But, i dont know who was the first srivaisnava acharya to quote bhagavatham .

Comment: @Krishna Did Ramanujacharya's disciples ever quote from the Srimad Bhagavatam?

Comment: As far as Ramanuja went his purpose was to drag in 4000 divya prabandham and reconcile it with the vedas ,the 4000 itself being the kernel of the vedas and satvic puranas,one effect is the divya prabandam group in front of the lord with his consorts followed by the vedas at the rear whenever the lord comes out of the temple or even for that matter the routine inside the temple.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan can you please give me link to Ramanujacharya's Commentary on Bhagavatam?

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande Ramanujacharya never wrote a commentary on the Srimad Bhagavatam or any other Purana.  He only wrote two commentaries: a commentary on the Brahma Sutras and a commentary on the Bhagavad Gita.  But other Sri Vaishnava Acharyas have written commentaries on the Bhagavatam, although none of them have been translated into English.  Do you know Sanskrit?  If so I can give you the links to Sanskrit Sri Vaishanava commentary on the Bhagavatam.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan no I dont understand Sanskrit. I refer to vedabase for Bhagavatam. But I wasnt convinced with translation on passing away of Bhishma in 1.9.43-44. So i wanted to read a comentary of some other Vaishnava Acarya.

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande OK, there is a book by S. Subbarao that gives the Advaita, Dvaita, and Visistadvaita interpretation of each Srimad Bhagavatam verse.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan can you please give me link?

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande Vishwanath Chakravarty on 1.9.44 The ignorant, who were like birds who think that day has been destroyed at the approach of evening, thought that Bhéñma had attained the brahman, and became silent. 

COMMENTARY 
Bhéñma had attained his cherished form of Kåñëa as the charioteer, but the common people, not knowing this though that he had entered into brahman. That is expressed in this verse. An example of ignorance is given. Birds, thinking that the day has been destroyed at the end of day because they cannot see it, become silent.

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande The day has not actually be destroyed, because one understands that after some time, that day still exists, since after twelve hours daylight appears again.The ignorant think that when Bhéñma passed away he attained liberation. The intelligent understand that at that very moment in an invisible form Bhéñma fights on the ground with Kåñëa holding the chariot wheel in his hand, and that in a future appearance of Kåñëa,
Bhéñma will also appear with him. Or brahmaëi niñkali can mean “into the brahman Kåñëa, who wears a gold ornament.”

Comment: @Vishalprabhulawande One should not explain that Bhéñma merged into the brahman,
 since by giving him something devoid of his goal, this would be cheating his eternal associate Bhéñma of prema, since Bhéñma did not desire liberation, and since it would be improper for the Lord to give undesired results forcibly